# Crear una lista dinámica en C# y SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

estoy aprendiendo `MVC` con `C#` y `asp.net` y me he topado con un problema. En mi página de ejemplo que es una ABC de cursos, al momento de crear un Grupos, necesito conseguir los ID's y la descripción de los Maestros y los Cursos. Entonces creé un `SP` que consulte los Id's de maestro y lo mandé a llamar con este método en mi acceso a datos:

```
 public List<CAT_MAESTRO> consultarIdsMaestros()
    {
        conn.Open();
        DataTable dtDatos = new DataTable();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("usp_consultarIdsMaestro", conn);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlDataAdapter SQLDtAd = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        SQLDtAd.Fill(dtDatos);
        SQLDtAd.Dispose();

        command.Dispose();

        conn.Close();

        List<CAT_MAESTRO> lstMaestro = new List<CAT_MAESTRO>();
        foreach (DataRow row in dtDatos.Rows)
        {
            lstMaestro.Add(
                new CAT_MAESTRO
                {
                    ID_MAESTRO = int.Parse(row["ID_MAESTRO"].ToString()),
                    AP_PATERNO = row["AP_PATERNO"].ToString(),
                    AP_MATERNO = row["AP_MATERNO"].ToString(),
                    NOMBRE = row["NOMBRE"].ToString(),

                }
            );
        }
        return lstMaestro;

    }
```

Pero ahora quiero llamar esa lista a mi controlador de Grupos, estaba haciendo esto:

```
  List<SelectListItem>  lstMaestro = new List<SelectListItem>();


ViewBag.vwMaestro = lstMaestro;
```

en mi controlador y en mi vista ya mandar a llamar mi lista, pero no entiendo muy bien esta parte. Espero me haya dado a entender, muchas gracias

Comment: Estas pasando a tu vista una lista diferente a la del procedimiento de arriba. ese es el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que comentas esa lista la quieres usar para cargar una combo o lista, en ese caso seria algo como esto

```
var maestros = dataAccess.consultarIdsMaestros();
var lstMaestro = new SelectList(maestros, "ID_MAESTRO", "NOMBRE");

ViewBag.vwMaestro = lstMaestro;
```

en la view lo usarias

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Maestro, ViewBag.vwMaestro , "Seleccione un maestro")
```